# unlinking copied instance variables in java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to `java` and I want to be able to change an instance variable whose values have been copied from an other instance and I get some weird results. Here's some simple code

class DummyBean {

```
private Integer[] instant = new Integer[9];

private Integer state;

Integer[] getInstant() {
    return instant;
}

void setInstant(Integer[] arr) {
    for(int index =0;index<9;index++)
        this.instant[index] = arr[index];
}

Integer getState() {
    return state;
}

void setState(Integer state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public DummyBean(){
}
String getDummy() {
    return dummy;
}

void setDummy(String dummy) {
    this.dummy = dummy;
}

private String dummy;

public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
    this.dummy = another.getDummy();
    this.instant = another.getInstant();
    this.state = another.getState();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    DummyBean dum = new DummyBean();
    Integer[] test = new Integer[9];
    for(int index =0;index<9;index++)
        test[index] = 1;
    dum.setInstant(test);
    dum.setState(10);

    System.out.println(dum.getInstant()[0]);
    System.out.println(dum.getState());

    DummyBean dumtwo = new DummyBean(dum);
    System.out.println(dumtwo.getInstant()[0]);
    System.out.println(dumtwo.getState());

    dum.getInstant()[0] = 2;
    dum.setState(20);
    System.out.println(dum.getInstant()[0]);
    System.out.println(dum.getState());
    System.out.println(dumtwo.getInstant()[0]);
    System.out.println(dumtwo.getState());

}
```

}

So I get

```
1
10

1
10


2
20

2
10
```

Among the last two values, I understand that `dumtwo` state instance did not change, but why dumtwo `instant` variable change accordingly to `dum` change ?

Btw, bow to get the copied `dumtwo` not inherit from `dum` changes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because in your copy constructor the `dum` and `dumtwo` are referenced to the same array, you didn't copy the array in your constructor:

```
public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
    this.dummy = another.getDummy();
    this.instant = another.getInstant();
    this.state = another.getState();
}
```

So any change in instance from any object it will affect the others.

Finally you need to make a new copy of your instance array, so you could use :

```
System.arraycopy();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you copy the array reference `this.instant = another.getInstant();`. As an array is an `Object` with state it can be modified.

`Integer` and `String` are both immutable, so copying reference is fine.

You need to either make `setInstant` `final`:

```
final void setInstant(Integer[] arr) {
    for(int index =0;index<9;index++)
        this.instant[index] = arr[index];
}
```

And use that in your constructor:

```
public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
    this.dummy = another.getDummy();
    setInstant(another.getInstant();
    this.state = another.getState();
}
```

Or use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

P.S. please format and organise your code according to Java conventions:

```
public class DummyBean {

    private Integer[] instant = new Integer[9];
    private Integer state;
    private String dummy;

    public DummyBean() {
    }

    public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
        this.dummy = another.getDummy();
        setInstant(another.getInstant());
        this.state = another.getState();
    }

    Integer[] getInstant() {
        return instant;
    }

    final void setInstant(Integer[] arr) {
        for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            this.instant[index] = arr[index];
        }
    }

    Integer getState() {
        return state;
    }

    void setState(Integer state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    String getDummy() {
        return dummy;
    }

    void setDummy(String dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
    }
}
```

i.e. First variable declarations. Then constructors. Finally methods.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're referencing the same object `instant` for `dum` and `dumtwo`. What you can do in your constructor is this

```
public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
    this.dummy = another.getDummy();
    this.instant = setArrayCopy(another);
    this.state = another.getState();
}

private Integer[] setArrayCopy(DummyBean another){
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[9];
    for(int index =0;index<9;index++)
        arr[index] = another.getInstant()[index];
    return arr;
}
```

this because you may want not to make `setInstant` final, and this scales when your `instant` variable is not an array, but some class and you would not be able to use `System.arraycopy()`

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same Integer array for both instances of DummyBean. If you want each to have their own Integer array, you need to make a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you'll get your answer:

```
    System.out.println(dum.instant.toString());
    System.out.println(dumtwo.instant.toString());
```